# escape domain name characters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't for my life figure this out. I am trying to implement the following SQL query:

```
  DECLARE @variable varchar(8000)
  SELECT @variable = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("LinkedServerName", ''SELECT objectGUID FROM ''LDAP://bla1.bla2'' WHERE name = ''myName mySurname'' '')'
  EXEC (@variable)
```

I just can't seem to be able to escape this guy

```
 ''LDAP://bla1.bla2''
```

I've tried many different options: double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, % symbol before slashes... It's not working. However, it works perfectly with double quotes in a query of a different format like so:

```
 SELECT * FROM OpenQuery 
 (
  "LinkedServerName", 'SELECT objectGUID FROM ''LDAP://bla1.bla2'' WHERE name =  
''myName mySurname'' '
 )
```

But query of this format does not work for me, because I want to save its result in a variable.

-Any ideas on how to escape the domain name in the first query?

-If not, any ideas on how to save an open query result in a variable with the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(8000)
  SELECT @variable = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY("LinkedServerName", ''SELECT objectGUID FROM ''''LDAP://bla1.bla2'''' WHERE name = ''''myName mySurname'''' '')'
  PRINT (@variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just substitute the value:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000);

SELECT @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY("LinkedServerName",
               ''SELECT objectGUID FROM ''[var]'' WHERE name = ''myName mySurname'' ''
              )';

SELECT @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '[var]', 'LDAP://bla1.bla2')

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I would also suggest that you learn to use `sp_executesql`.  It is more powerful than merely using `exec()`.